# How to find the path to the file in Python?

Tags: pycharm

(Windows) I have a file called: text.txt visible in the column on the left-hand side of my screen. After right-clicking on that file I should see "Show in Explorer", but I can't see such a command.
[image]

I was wondering if it might have to do something with the fact, that I struggle to save my Python work, and can't edit ZIP files in Python.

Comment: Is this a Visual Studio, or Visual Code question?

Comment: @quamrana that doesn't look like VSCode

Comment: @quamrana It's `pycharm`

Comment: So not a python question at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Copy Path/Reference` will give you the path

Answer (score 1):

On the menu in your image, go to `Open In >`, then click `Explorer` in the submenu.

Answer (score 1):

After right click, click on open in.. Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

right-click on "text.txt", then click "Open in", then click "Explorer"